# Error with my code?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm making a project for my school.

It's a page-source viewer, but I've ran in to a problem..

Using google chrome, I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : main.php:10`

**HTML**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Codeview - See how your code turns out!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        var url = <?php echo "$url"; ?>
        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            oReq.open("GET", url, true);
            console.log(oReq.response);
        </script>
        <div id="header">
            <h2>Codeview</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <br>
            <h3>Code of <?php  echo $url;?>:</h3>
            <hr>
            <div id="code">
            </div>
            <iframe id="Code" class="code"></iframe>
        </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

**PHP**:

```
<?php
function contains($needle, $haystack)
{
    return strpos($haystack, $needle) !== true;
}
$url = $_POST['url'];

if (strpos($url, "http://") !== false) {
$url = $url;
} else {
$url = "http://" . $url;
}

?>
```

I cant find a colon (:) anywhere on line 10 in my code..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a JavaScript error. Show us the client side code, not the server side code that generates it.

Comment: My guess would be that you're missing quotes around the url you're echoing, ending up with `var url = http: ...`; that's where your unexpected : comes from.

Comment: You need to look at the source of the page.  The code that's rendered by PHP.

Comment: Why are you using native JavaScript's `XMLHttpRequest` when using jQuery?

Comment: So far you have 5 valid answers and another answer in the comments. You need to accept this.

Answer (score 9):

This: `var url = <?php echo "$url"; ?>`

Will output something like:

```
var url = http://example.com
```

Strings in JavaScript need to be quoted. You are also vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Use `json_encode` to convert a PHP string to a JavaScript string.

It is also good practise not to depend on semi-colon insertion.

```
var url = <?php echo json_encode("$url"); ?>;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need quotes around strings in JavaScript.

```
var url = <?php echo "$url"; ?>
```

This renders as:

```
var url = http://google.com
```

That's a syntax error!  Try this:

```
var url = <?php echo json_encode($url); ?>;
```

That will add the quotes for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use quotes when printing into the variable declaration in your JS code:

```
var url = "<?php echo $url; ?>";
```

**But don't use this code!** It is vulnerable to [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks. To escape the URL in the javascript context, use `json_encode`:

```
var url = <?php echo json_encode($url); ?>;   /* this one is safe */
```

Answer (score 1):

As a first step you should add quotes to your js var

```
var url = '<?php echo "$url"; ?>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
var url = <?php echo "$url"; ?>
```

to this:

```
var url = '<?php echo "$url"; ?>';
```

Answer (score -2):

Try adding a semicolon to the end of this line and also wrap the PHP code in quotes:

```
var url = "<?php echo "$url"; ?>";
```